# Nouveau driver works with Wayland but not with X11

Tags: xorg

I am trying to login to GNOME X11 with the Nouveau driver. This does not work (see attached `xorg.log` file). However, Wayland does work fine and I can login.

If I install the proprietary drivers for NVIDIA, I can also login to X11.

What could be stopping me from logging in to X11 with Nouveau? How would you troubleshoot this?

Log file: https://pastebin.com/LaDwXUvt

EDIT: additonal info:

uname -a

Linux aragorn 5.11.0-16-generic #17-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 20:12:43 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Ubuntu version = ubuntu+1 impish.

Wayland reports NVD9 driver (Gforce 520M)

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? What graphics card? Please [edit] your question and add the output of  `uname -a` and `lspci | grep VGA` .

Comment: Thanks I have added the info.

Comment: I voted to close the question because Ubuntu+1 is off-topic in Ask Ubuntu. Please read the relevant help center topic: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) As it is a development version, issues such as the one in your question are almost certain to occur. You should report them on Launchpad so that the developers become aware of them and fix them. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I will just wait 6 months then ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by renaming the .Xauthority file in my home directoy and letting it get recreated after rebooting. Now everything works fine in X11 (using open source nouveau).
Somehow the file was corrupt as I could bot display any text in that file.

As this was the root cause for x11 not working on my system, I will leave this up in case anyone else has the same issue.